# MailChimp "Your advanced segment is empty"

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm attempting to send to a list using the MailChimp API, but when calling `campaigns/{campaign_id}/actions/send` I receive the response `Your campaign is not ready to send`.

However, if login to MailChimp, I can see the message is clearly ready to send:

[image]

Moreover, I can send the email manually.

Now, making a request to /campaigns/{campaign_id}/send-checklist yields the following issue:

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => error
                [id] => 501
                [heading] => List
                [details] => Your advanced segment is empty.
            )
```

Everything else is a success, as per the attached screenshot.

However, my list has no segments, nor are segments a required parameter when creating the campaign.

Has anyone any idea what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 0):

The contacts in an advanced segment are pulled at the time you create it, and do not automatically update. To update your contact count before a new or scheduled campaign is sent, you'll need to manually refresh the segment.

https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/advanced-segments/create-an-advanced-segment

Comment: Is there any way to do this via API?  I cannot see an endpoint for it.

Comment: Until now, is NOT possible to run "Update recipients count" by API?